# Generating attribute values of a certain node in file in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have some xml files in which there are nodes for sections of an article like

```
MAIN SECTIONS:
<section id="sec1">
<section id="sec2">
...
```

There respective sub-sections like

```
1ST SUBSECTIONS:
<section id="sec1a">
<section id="sec1b">
...
```

then sub-sections like

```
2ND SUBSECTIONS:
<section id="sec1a1">
<section id="sec1a2">
...
```

& their sub-sections

```
FINALLY 3RD SUBSECTIONS:
<section id="sec1a1a">
<section id="sec1a1b">
...
```

The closing node of these sections are put when a section of a particular type ends and starts a new one
e.x.

```
<section id="sec1">
<p>....</p>
</section>
<section id="sec2">
or
<section id="sec1">
<p>....</p>
<section id="sec1a">
<p>...</p>
</section>
<section id="sec2">
or
<section id="sec1">
<p>....</p>
<section id="sec1a">
<section id="sec1a1">
<p>...</p>
</section>
</section>
</section>
<section id="sec2">
```

and so on...
But my files have the id attribute values all mixed up..
Is there a way to format it using the closing node `</section>` as an identifier.?

Sample file content

```
<section id="sec1">
<label>1.</label>
<title>INTRODUCTION</title>
<p>Despite the large number of scientific papers devoted to the heart <sup><xref ref-type="bibr" rid="c1">1</xref>&#x2013;<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="c2">2</xref></sup>, this time to think both home and foreign authors there are many different controversial issues. They are associated with morphological structural features of valvular heart disease and its individual structural components: valves, tendon strings mastoid muscle and fibrous ring <sup><xref ref-type="bibr" rid="c1">1</xref>&#x2013;<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="c2">2</xref></sup>.</p>
<section id="sec2">
<title>INTRO</title>
<p>All structures are large valvular morphofunctional load.</p>
<p>According to the classification of tendon strings of the heart they are classified as boundary, i.e, those that are attached to the edges of the leaves, leaf, spot fixing being lower surface of leaf valve (facing the cavity of the ventricle) and abnormally arranged strings.</p>
<p>Thus detailed knowledge of the structural features of normal tendon strings.</p>
</section>
</section>
<section id="sec3">
<label>2.</label>
<title>THE MORPHOLOGY OF CHONDRAE TENDIANEAE</title>
<section id="sec2a">
<title>THE MORPHOLOGY</title>
<p>According to the macroscopic study of tendon strings newborns and infants</p>
<section id="sec5a1">
<title>THE OML</title>
<p>Total number of tendon strings are attached to the cusps of atrioventricular valves of the heart in both age groups ranged from 30 to 80.</p>
</section>
</section>
</section>
```

Expected output

```
<section id="sec1">
<label>1.</label>
<title>INTRODUCTION</title>
<p>Despite the large number of scientific papers devoted to the heart <sup><xref ref-type="bibr" rid="c1">1</xref>&#x2013;<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="c2">2</xref></sup>, this time to think both home and foreign authors there are many different controversial issues. They are associated with morphological structural features of valvular heart disease and its individual structural components: valves, tendon strings mastoid muscle and fibrous ring <sup><xref ref-type="bibr" rid="c1">1</xref>&#x2013;<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="c2">2</xref></sup>.</p>
<section id="sec1a">
<title>INTRO</title>
<p>All structures are large valvular morphofunctional load.</p>
<p>According to the classification of tendon strings of the heart they are classified as boundary, i.e, those that are attached to the edges of the leaves, leaf, spot fixing being lower surface of leaf valve (facing the cavity of the ventricle) and abnormally arranged strings.</p>
<p>Thus detailed knowledge of the structural features of normal tendon strings.</p>
</section>
</section>
<section id="sec2">
<label>2.</label>
<title>THE MORPHOLOGY OF CHONDRAE TENDIANEAE</title>
<section id="sec2a">
<title>THE MORPHOLOGY</title>
<p>According to the macroscopic study of tendon strings newborns and infants</p>
<section id="sec2a1">
<title>THE OML</title>
<p>Total number of tendon strings are attached to the cusps of atrioventricular valves of the heart in both age groups ranged from 30 to 80.</p>
</section>
</section>
</section>
```

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. It is not clear if the problem is when you serialize or deserialize. Are you trying to transform an existing xml?

Comment: @KernelMode yes, I'm trying to the transform an existing xml..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a recursive algorithm.  See code below.  I'm not sure your numbering scheme with the small sample you posted.  I did the numbering a little different.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            RecusiveParse(root, 1, "sec");
        }
        static void RecusiveParse(XElement parent, int level, string parentId)
        {
            int index = 1;
            foreach (XElement child in parent.Elements("section"))
            {
                string id = "";
                if (level % 2 == 0)
                {
                    string prefix = ((char)('a' + (index - 1))).ToString();
                    id = parentId + prefix;
                }
                else
                {
                    id = parentId + index.ToString();
                }

                child.Attribute("id").Value = id;
                RecusiveParse(child, level + 1, id);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the number schemes are like 

Main section `id=sec1, id=sec2 ... `, then 1st sub-section sec1 `sec1a`, 2nd sub-section sec1 `sec1b`...so on , then 1st sub-section of `sec1a/sec1b` will be `sec1a1, sec1a2/sec1b1, sec1b2` and so on.. if they exist, there could also be that between `<section id="sec2">` and `<section id="sec3">` there are no sub-sections..Hope I made it a little clearer :)

Comment: The code doesn't work because a well formated xml has only one root tag.  Your code has multiple tags at the root level.  I assumed you had a root tag.  I also thought that last id should be sec2ab1,

Comment: I tried adding a single root element but it still did not do anything...The last id should be 2a1, also do you get the closing node `</section>` logic?

Comment: Putting <root> at beginning and </root> of existing input should update the doc.

Comment: I tried that..but it doesn't update the doc...the code just runs without any errors but the file is unchanged...

Comment: Are you sure?  Did you try saving file to see if it got changed?

Comment: Oops...Yeah I forgot to add the save command, but now the output is not what I wanted..did you see my expected output part in my question?

Comment: Thanks....do you mind explaining `RecusiveParse` method...how does it work?

Comment: For every nested tag "section" it calls itself with the level variable incremented by one and the current id string.  The the for loop it increments the index by one so each sibling section element get a value one high than the previous and appending the id string to the parent id string.  Since it looks like the id at each level alternates between numeric id and alpha id (even levels are alpha and odd levels numeric) I have code that increments the alpha as well as the numeric id.